# Can I enter a '?' in a date range in a pass-through query so I can enter a date range in a form in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In access is there a way to create a pass-through query that doesn't retain a hard coded date? For example, I have a form linked to a pass through query and I want to be able to enter in a date range via the form and have it update the pass-through query. Here is my current query but I prefer that it is a date range with a '?' or something that would allow for a prompt for a date range or for me to put in a date range via the form. Can this be done? Or must I use VBA?

```
select distinct fill_sold_dt ,pf.str_nbr,wic_nbr, pkg_sz, pkg_qty, sum(fill_qty_dspn), sum((fill_qty_dspn)/(pkg_sz*pkg_qty) ) as Packs 
 from
prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sold pf, prdedwvwh.location_store_address_cur lsa, prdedwvwh.drug_cur d
where pf.str_nbr=lsa.str_nbr and
d.drug_id=pf.drug_id
and fill_sold_dt(DATE) >= CURRENT_DATE - 7
 and wic_nbr in (683378,335776,418723)

group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Where do you want to put the range?  Are you going to convert `fill_sold_dt(DATE) >= CURRENT_DATE - 7` to a `BETWEEN`?  If so you could have two inputs, one for the start and one for the end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use VBA. 
If you dont know how to accomplish this in VBA, you can check exemple 2 on this page:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131534

***Edit*** - Adding full exemple

Create 2 textboxes of type date on your form and name them DateStart and DateEnd

Create a button with a click event like this :

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    GetDataFromDate DateStart.value, DateENd.value

End Sub
```

And add this Sub to your form :

```
Sub GetDataFromDate(dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date)

 Dim MyDb As Database, MyQry As QueryDef, MyRS  As Recordset
 Set MyDb = CurrentDb()
 Set MyQry = MyDb.CreateQueryDef("")

 ' Type a connect string using the appropriate values for your
 ' server.
 MyQry.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=user1;UID=user1;PWD=user1;DATABASE=TEST"

 ' Set the SQL query with Date Range passed to the sub as parameters
 MyQry.SQL = " SELECT distinct fill_sold_dt ,pf.str_nbr,wic_nbr, pkg_sz, pkg_qty, sum(fill_qty_dspn) as som, sum((fill_qty_dspn)/(pkg_sz*pkg_qty) ) as Packs " & _
             " FROM prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sold pf, prdedwvwh.location_store_address_cur lsa, prdedwvwh.drug_cur d " & _
             " WHERE pf.str_nbr=lsa.str_nbr and d.drug_id = pf.drug_id and wic_nbr in (683378,335776,418723)" & _
             "   AND fill_sold_dt BETWEEN #" & dtStart & "# AND #" & dtEnd & "# " & _
             " GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5 "

 MyQry.ReturnsRecords = True
 Set MyRS = MyQry.OpenRecordset()

 MyRS.MoveFirst

 If Not MyRS.BOF Then

    While Not MyRS.EOF

        Debug.Print MyRS!fill_sold_dt
        Debug.Print MyRS!str_nbr
        Debug.Print MyRS!pkg_sz
        Debug.Print MyRS!som
        Debug.Print MyRS!Packs

        MyRS.MoveNext
    Wend


 End If

 MyQry.Close
 MyRS.Close
 MyDb.Close

End Sub
```

Here you go

Comment: Cool, I am trying this. can you explain what I do with the below...Is this where I will set the date range parameter? Any idea of how I can write that?                                                     " Set the SQL property and concatenate the variables.
         MyQry.SQL = "sp_server_info " & MyParam"

Comment: Great! And suppose I wanted to add more parameters, for Wic_nbr for example, would i just put in a condition (and wic_nbr "&WIC&") to link to the WIC text box on my form?

Comment: Just check what I did for the dateStart and dateEnd and reproduce it. You have to declare any additional parameter between the () parentesis next to your Sub's name, then add them in your query by concatanation using & operator (like I did with 2 dates) and finally add them in the call to your sub in yoyr button's click event.
Additionally, you should do some google search about VBA basics, like string concatanations and Sub/Function use.